# How to sort columns within a row in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

The output of my calculation looks something like:

| A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.1 | 0.2 | 0 | 0.7 | 0.22 | 0.11 |

I want to order these values while keeping them labeled, so the output here would have to be:

| D | E | B | F | A | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.7 | 0.22 | 0.2 | 0.11 | 0.1 | 0 |

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `sort_values` on the first row:

```
df.sort_values(by=0, axis=1, ascending=False)
```

output:

```
     D     E    B     F    A  C
0  0.7  0.22  0.2  0.11  0.1  0
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us do

```
out = df.T.sort_values(0,ascending=False).T
Out[106]: 
     D     E    B     F    A    C
0  0.7  0.22  0.2  0.11  0.1  0.0
```

Comment: `sort_values` takes an `axis` argument ;)